# CORS issue when consuming external federation module in Vite

Tags: vite

I'm currently getting a

*'Access to script at 'https://www.example.com/remoteEntry.js' from origin 'http://localhost:5005' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.'*

issue when trying to consume an external micro frontend component in Vite.

I've tried to run both the npm run dev and npm run preview but still getting the same CORS issue

I've tried loading http://www.example.com/remoteEntry.js (real domain replaced) and the file loads fine on the browser

Here is my Vite config

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import federation from "@originjs/vite-plugin-federation";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    federation({
      name: 'host-app',
      remotes: {
        remoteApp: "http://www.example.com/remoteEntry.js",
      },
      shared: ['react', 'react-dom']
    })
  ],
  preview: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5005,
    strictPort: true,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
    },
    cors: {
      origin: ["*"]
    }
  },
  build: {
    target: 'esnext' // needed to final build
  },
  server: {
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
    },
  }
```

what am i missing?

Thank you so much!